# Local static variable in template across shared library

Tags: c++, templates, static, rtti

I'm trying to generate a unique index for each typename.
This generation needs to work across shared library meanings
that it has to be done at runtime.

**Example:**

```
size_t id0 = componentSection<Type1>();
size_t id1 = componentSection<Type2>();
size_t id2 = componentSection<Type1>();
return (id0 == id2 && id1 != id0 && id1 != id2);
```

I use a static variable in template.

**Code suggestion:**

```
private:
    template<typename C>
    size_t generateNewSection() noexcept
    {
        m_componentLists.emplace_back(std::make_unique<ComponentList<C>>());
        return m_componentLists.size() - 1;
    }

public:
    template<typename C>
    size_t componentSection() noexcept
    {
        static size_t section = generateNewSection<C>();
        return section;
    }
```

As you can see, I use the initialization property of static to make sure 
the index remains the same.

**Problem:**

Generated index are not the same across shared libraries because the static
variable is "regenerated" for each library. I should move the static
definition in a source file to make sure the address will be the same.
But I can't because I use templates ... Each static variables can't be linked.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

My question has been set to deplicated but I still don't kown how to solve my
problem. I understand the problem of static with shared library but is there a solution ?

**Solution**

I finally decided to choose this solution:

```
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, size_t> m_indexes;

    template<typename C>
    size_t getSection() noexcept
    {
        std::type_index index = std::type_index(typeid(C));

        if(m_indexes.find(index) != m_indexes.end())
            return m_indexes.at(index);

        m_componentLists.emplace_back(std::make_unique<ComponentList<C>>());
        m_indexes[index] = m_componentLists.size() - 1;

        return m_componentLists.size() - 1;
    }

public:
    template<typename C>
    size_t componentSection() noexcept
    {
        static size_t section = getSection<C>();
        return section;
    }
```

Comment: Are you on windows or *nix? By shared library, do you mean run-time or load-time linking?

Comment: Why don't you use `typeid` / `type_index`?

Comment: I'm on both, Windows and unix. I'm using load-time linking but I may have to do with run-time linking for a future plugin system.

Comment: I don't use typeid / type_index because I need to convert them to a linear index (array random access) which is expensive.